# Is the current standard specification on std::span default constructor correct on "Extent <= 0"?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, c++20

As of April 21, 2019, 02:44:49 UTC, the version of [[span.cons]](http://eel.is/c++draft/span.cons#1) on https://eel.is/c++draft/ seems to contain a mistake:

> ```
> constexpr span() noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Constraints:* `Extent <= 0` is `true`. 
>   *Ensures:* `size() == 0 && data() == nullptr`.

`Extent` has been adjusted to be of `size_t` type,
and `dynamic_extent` is now `numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.
Therefore, `Extent <= 0` is essentially equivalent to `Extent == 0`.
That is, the constructor is disabled when the extent is dynamic,
which is probably not intended.

I guess the intent is `Extent == 0 || Extent == dynamic_extent`
since this works when `dynamic_extent` was signed.

Is this a bug in the standard? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [LWG3198](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3198).  It was discussed this week and should officially be fixed in August.